# how to disable past dates in DatePicker of javaFx (scene builder)

Tags: javafx, datepicker

I created on the scene builder a DatePicker. I want to make it disable dates, in order to force user to pick dates from the current day, but I don't know how to do it. all examples I saw were not in java (and of course my project is in java).

Comment: See the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/date-picker.htm#CCHHJBEA). It has an example "Implementing a Day Cell Factory to Disable Some Days".

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue. Here's the piece of code that worked for me.

```
DatePicker dp = new DatePicker();
dp.setDayCellFactory(picker -> new DateCell() {
        public void updateItem(LocalDate date, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(date, empty);
            LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

            setDisable(empty || date.compareTo(today) < 0 );
        }
    });
```

This will make unavaiable those days that compared to the LocalDate.now() (wich returns the current day date) are smaller, so the previous days.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Callback<DatePicker, DateCell> callB = new Callback<DatePicker, DateCell>() {
            @Override
            public DateCell call(final DatePicker param) {
                return new DateCell() {
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(LocalDate item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
                        setDisable(empty || item.compareTo(today) < 0);
                    }

                };
            }

        };
        selectedDate.setDayCellFactory(callB);
```

disable past dates in date picker